# How give array name from string variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables

I am stuck with a situation where I need to give array name from string variable.

Basically I want to create an array with same name as value in another string variable "name":

```
char *name="arr_name";
```

In my case the string being hold by variable name may change. Hence advice accroding.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: C is not an interpreted language

Comment: C can't do what you want, but at the same time there's probably no reason to want it. What do you wish to achieve?

Comment: It's might be possible through the preprocessor, though, I can't imagine why it would be necessary.

Comment: There was a question like that 1-2 days ago. It had good answers. Umm... here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546385/accessing-a-variable-in-c-by-stitching-its-name-together/24546947#24546947, it's very related. It's explained why it's quite impossible, why, and what can you do instead. It's for c++ but most of the point hold true. Only the specific work around solutions might need to be adapted, still worth of reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for some mechanism, similar to the ones found in the higher level languages as in python (introspection), or C# (reflections). C doesn't provide this kind of insight from the runtime, not even the variable names are existing in the bytecode - so basically it's not possible and doesn't make any sense in the terms of the way how C works.

I don't know if that helps, but one thing you could do is to statically (so in the compilation time, not while it's running!) populate char* and create variable with the same name, given that the value of the string is a proper name for the variable ([Naming convention for C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B)). You can achieve that by defining a proper macro (`#define your_macro(...) code_to_populate_char_and_declare_variable`), but I cannot see any point in doing so.